# AdWords API in ASP.NET. Can I avoid using the `user` object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, google-api

The story is: I am building a Node application, but I need data from Google AdWords. Since there is no official Node library and I couldn't get the unofficial ones to work I wanted to create a REST API in ASP.NET. So far this is what I have:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    TargetingIdeaSelector selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector
    {
        requestType = RequestType.IDEAS,
        ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD,
        requestedAttributeTypes = new AttributeType[] {
    AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT,
    AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME,
    AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC,
    AttributeType.COMPETITION,
    AttributeType.CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES
}
    };

    // Set selector paging (required for targeting idea service).
    Paging paging = Paging.Default;

    // Create related to query search parameter.
    RelatedToQuerySearchParameter relatedToQuerySearchParameter =
        new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter
        {
            queries = new String[] {
        "bakery", "pastries", "birthday cake"
            }
        };
    var searchParameters = new List<SearchParameter>
        {
            relatedToQuerySearchParameter
        };

    TargetingIdeaPage page = new TargetingIdeaPage();
    page = targetingIdeaService.get(selector);
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I basically grabbed the code from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service). The problem is that the targetingIdeaService is not defined. If I try to take a look at a [code sample](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/csharp/optimization#get-keyword-ideas) it looks like this:

```
public void Run(AdWordsUser user, long? adGroupId) {
  using (TargetingIdeaService targetingIdeaService =
      (TargetingIdeaService) user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201802.TargetingIdeaService)) {
    // Create selector.
    TargetingIdeaSelector selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
    selector.requestType = RequestType.IDEAS;
    selector.ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD;
    selector.requestedAttributeTypes = new AttributeType[] {
      AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT,
      AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME,
      AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC,
      AttributeType.COMPETITION,
      AttributeType.CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES
    };


    List<SearchParameter> searchParameters = new List<SearchParameter>();

    // Create related to query search parameter.
    RelatedToQuerySearchParameter relatedToQuerySearchParameter =
        new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter();
    relatedToQuerySearchParameter.queries = new String[] {
      "bakery", "pastries", "birthday cake"
    };
    searchParameters.Add(relatedToQuerySearchParameter);
```

And a lot more code. The point is they made it in a function, and are passing a `user` object into it. Now I will not have said object. Unless it's needed. Then I'm screwed. But I need to get this service up and running. This is the only missing step, other than that it should work.

So my question is: Does anyone see a way around it?

Comment: The user object is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AdWordsUser object contains the authentication you need to connect to the API. Without it your app will have no idea of which AdWords account and OAuth refresh token to supply to the TargetingIdeaService.

Comment: Could I create the `AdWordsUser` on the ASP.NET side? This is the one with refresh token, access token, client id and so on?

Comment: You'll need to create the AdWordsUser in the ASP.NET application.

Comment: Yes. I tried that and posted another question about that. If you're interested there is more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906653/google-adwords-library-doesnt-create-an-access-token)