# Google AdWords library doesn't create an access token

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, google-api

I'm trying to make a *targetingIdeaService* API call to Google AdWords. This is my code so far:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    var user = new AdWordsUser();

    using (TargetingIdeaService targetingIdeaService = (TargetingIdeaService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201802.TargetingIdeaService))
    {
        // Create selector.
        TargetingIdeaSelector selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
        selector.requestType = RequestType.IDEAS;
        selector.ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD;
        selector.requestedAttributeTypes = new AttributeType[] {
            AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT,
            AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME,
            AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC,
            AttributeType.COMPETITION,
            AttributeType.CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES
        };

        // Set selector paging (required for targeting idea service).
        var paging = Paging.Default;
        // Create related to query search parameter.
        var relatedToQuerySearchParameter =
            new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter
            { queries = new String[] { "bakery", "pastries", "birthday cake" } };
        var searchParameters = new List<SearchParameter> { relatedToQuerySearchParameter };

        var page = new TargetingIdeaPage();
        page = targetingIdeaService.get(selector);
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

it looks ok, compiles at last, and so on. But then I went into debug mode. And I saw this:

[image]

So as you can see, the variable doesn't have the ***access token***. The other data comes from `app.config` file.

I am quite certain the keys passed in are correct.

Then the code throws the famous `invalid_grand` error. In my case, I believe that's because the access token is not being generated. I'm new to AdWords and ASP.NET, so I probably missed something, but I have no idea what.

I used the 
[docs](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service), 
[Code Structure instructions](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/samples-use-cases), and 
[code examples](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/csharp/optimization#get-keyword-ideas) to put it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my configuration wrong. I had to recreate all the credentials using incognito window. If you have any issues just open a thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api